# How to remove glue from ceiling

Tags: ceiling, removal, adhesive

I removed a ceiling of plaster panels and found that on the original concrete ceiling there is a glue residue of some glued-on styrofoam tiles. (See picture)

[image: glue on ceiling]

Before I get the plastering redone, I have to remove this residue. Are there like special glue removers for this type of work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you reuse the furring.  Here is my reasoning

- It's already there.
- It will cost more to remove it than reuse it
- It will provide space to run electrical, network, phone, coax, etc wiring
- Unless you head height is really low, the 1.5" will not be missed too much.

Essentially, you have a 'service cavity'.  You can place low profile can lights, electrical wiring, etc in this space.  I'd keep it if it is secure.

Answer (score 0):

[How to remove construction adhesive from concrete?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/26154/how-to-remove-construction-adhesive-from-concrete)

---

Is there any other reason it is furred-out (electric runs, ect.)? It looks like someone tried to scrape a little, gave up and furred it. At the state it's currently in, I'm guessing your trying to see if this is a possibility or whether you are going to have to reuse the furring strips also. I see a few options:

- Have fun scraping
- Reuse the furring
- Scrape what you have to; plasterers skim coat the whole thing
- Get a quote just leaving it for the plasterers to deal with

I would suggest *trying* some of the linked suggestions before you pull down the furring. Anything besides just reusing them isn't going to be fun.